# Laravel Capsule set primary key

Tags: php, laravel, orm, eloquent

I want to implement a layer between my custom framework and Eloquent, in other words I want use the Eloquent as an ORM for my framework...

I started with this https://github.com/illuminate/database

As you can see looks quite simple, after booting up the Eloquent, the Capsule become available like this:

```
Capsule::table('users')->where('votes', '>', 100)->get();
```

Same way should work this:

```
Capsule::table('users')->find(3);
```

Where the Eloquent finds user `id=3`

But what would be, if the table primary key set something else like `user_id`

I know In Laravel I can set in model primary key

```
public $primaryKey = 'user_id';
```

But unfortunately, this is not my case, so I wander if Laravel developers does not implement something for other developers to make it easy to use Eloqunet for other frameworks or at least I can't find it out?

Please help me with this.. let me know if you need me to write more details...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't using just the query builder.  You can look at the code of Query/Builder.php and see that the find method is hard coded with id:

```
/**
 * Execute a query for a single record by ID.
 *
 * @param  int    $id
 * @param  array  $columns
 * @return mixed|static
 */
public function find($id, $columns = ['*'])
{
    return $this->where('id', '=', $id)->first($columns);
}
```

Just use `where('user_id', $id)->first()` if you don't want to follow Laravel conventions and are just using the query builder.

Beyond that, Eloquent Models should function the way you want, but you wouldn't use Capsule for those queries.